# Add html attributes to @Html.BeginForm that posts to an Async Task<ActionResult> method

Tags: asynchronous, model-view-controller, actionresult

I'm stuck trying to post to an Async Taskmethod.

If I leave the `BeginForm()` like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
```

or like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

it all works fine. But if I add Html attributes like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "b-form b-contact-form m-contact-form", style = "margin-bottom:10px;", role="form" }))
```

It doesnt post and I get this on the Chrome Console

```
"POST http://localhost:19218/Home/Contact 500 (Internal Server Error)"
```

My async action method looks like this:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Contact(ContactRequest ContactRequest)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ContactRequest.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                db.ContactRequests.Add(ContactRequest);
                db.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.Sent = true;

                return RedirectToAction("Contact");
            }

            return View(ContactRequest);
        }
```

Im using MVC 5.1.0.0

I just saw the post is getting this response:
    The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

But I have `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in my form.